# How to use single angular controller with two different angular states(views)?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have two different views/states(extension, q_and_a) that have a tab called Notifications. And notification is a separate state with its own controller. 
Notifications controller would do exactly same thing for both extension and q_and_a with different notifiable_type and notifiable_id which i can send as stateparams.

How can i reuse the same notification controller with different state? or making the notification tab as a directive is a better solution than reusing it. (with considerable amount of rework though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is ok to reuse controller. There is [some plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OPRJ5AzxGABx4vsPP4XZ?p=preview) with these state defs:

```
.state('other', {
  url: "/other",
  templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
  controller: 'controllerParent',
})

.state('parent', {
  url: '/parent',
  templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
  controller: 'controllerParent',
})
```

both using the same controller:

```
app.controller('controllerParent', function($scope, $state){
})
```

And if you can supply them with the same set of parameters like `function($scope, $state, $stateParams,...)`, e.g. with resolve.. it will work for you

The reason is: controller is instantiated again and again. And different instance for each view. Even if the views are siblings of one parent state. That is the difference when compared with Factories, Services... which are singletons

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/OPRJ5AzxGABx4vsPP4XZ?p=preview)

Comment: Great if that helped, sir;) Enjoy amazing `UI-Router`